# DevExpress Spreadsheet Control - Hide / Show Group-By Buttons and Mimic Behaviour in Code

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, spreadsheet

I have a DevExpress Spreadsheet control in my winforms app (v 15.1). I would like to hide the column Headers ("A", "B", "C", etc) across the top of my sheet and the row headers along the left edge ("1", "2", "3", etc).

I would also like to add subtotals to my data. Doing so adds "Group-By" buttons ("1", "2", "3") which expands and collapses the subtotal input data. Here's an example of what I mean:

[image: Normal Group By]

However, when I hide the column headers, the group-by buttons disappear too so I cannot expand or collapse the data by level:

[image: Hidden Header Group By]

I can see I can expand/collapse groupings in code via the `worksheet.Range[rangeName].GroupRows(true);` or `worksheet.Range[rangeName].UnGroupRows(true);` calls (I'm still trying to find how to expand or collapse to a specified level - something like `GroupRows(true, 2);` to collapse down to level 2). The problem is, I still have the "tree" structure to the left of the grid, even if the column and row headers are turned off.

What I'm trying to figure out is:

- Ideally how to hide the column headers *but* show the "Group-By" buttons
- OR
- If that cannot be done, then hide the column headers AND the "Group-By Tree" that remains on the left edge of the grid and then add buttons labelled "1", "2" & "3" to the form which do the various levels of grouping when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CustomDrawColumnHeader`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraSpreadsheetSpreadsheetControl_CustomDrawColumnHeadertopic) event to visually hide the column headers.
Here is example:

```
private void spreadsheetControl1_CustomDrawColumnHeader(object sender, CustomDrawColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    var color = CommonSkins.GetSkin(UserLookAndFeel.Default).Colors.GetColor(CommonColors.Control);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(color), e.Bounds);

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: you legend. I don't know why I didn't think of trying to find a custromDraw event for the headers. Simple and elegent, your solution does exactly what I was trying to do.